# GA event tracking in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the Divi theme in Wordpress to setup event tracking with jquery.

For the initial test I've setup a button with CSS class ID get_started and then added the following script in the header, for some reason the event isn't triggering.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".get_started.et_pb_button").on("click", function(e){
            var id = e.target.id;
            ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Get Started');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Check the Network XHR tab to see if any data was sent.

Comment: Just check I have the following 1.Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token 2.JQMIGRATE Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

Comment: Realised the issue was Google tag manager.  Opted to use a plugin for event tracking called WP Google Analytics Events, easy to setup if you're a coding novice.